# remove <div> from a sharepoint list with powershell

Tags: 2010, list, web-part, powershell

I have a web part where a user adds a comment into a multi-line text field.  It was originally set up as a rich-text field but I need to change it to plain-text for reasons.  When I did so, all the comments added < div> or < p> to the comment and I need to mass remove this using power shell, to save me individually needing to edit thousands of comments.  can this be done?
[image: example of div in comments]

For reference, this is SharePoint 2010

Comment: Can you use regex or something like replace function in powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in your powershell script to strip off the html:

```
$string = <your rich text column>

$string -replace '<[^>]+>',''
```

If it is not working for you then try another solution given in below article:

[HTML to Text conversion in Powershell](http://winstonfassett.com/blog/2010/09/21/html-to-text-conversion-in-powershell/)